# How do I get a template helper to become non reactive?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm very new to Meteor (started yesterday) so bear with me.

I've got the following to try and get some messages from the server:

```
var messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    //Initial first few messages 

    Meteor.publish("messages", function () {
        return messages.find({}, {sort: {createdAt : -1}, limit: 2, reactive : false});
    });
}
```

And then a helper for the template:

```
Template.card.helpers({
    messages: function () {
        return messages.find({});
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="messages-slider">
    {{#each messages}}
        {{> message}}
    {{/each}}   
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the first couple of messages and keep them static in the DOM, basically - however, with the above code the template updates with the collection regardless. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reactive` option of find is client-only. Use it in your helper:

```
Session.set('ready', false);
Meteor.subscribe('messages', { onReady: function() {
    Session.set('ready', true);
}});

Template.card.helpers({
    messages: function () {
        if (Session.get('ready')) {
            return messages.find({}, {reactive: false});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When I do this the template doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: because it renders before the client has some data to display. Try to print  the result and test with and without the `{reactive:false}`

Comment: OK, I updated the code to account for that. Now the helper is reactive in terms of readiness of the subscription, but should not be reactive after that in terms of changes to the collection.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really promising! I'll take a look asap.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to Christian's answer:

I think you could probably solve the rendering-before-the-subscription-is-ready issue by wrapping the template in `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}]` so it won't render until the subscription is loaded. No need for `Session` variables in that case. For example:

```
Template.card.onCreated(function(){
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function() {
       instance.subscribe('messages'); 
    });
});

Template.card.helpers({
    messages: function() {
        messages.find({},{reactive:false});
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="card"> 
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        <div class="messages-slider">
            {{#each messages}}
                {{> message}}
            {{/each}}   
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```